# How do I change the output of theme_comment_submitted()?

Tags: theming

How to change the default theme of comment_submitted in drupal?

**Input:**

$variables['submitted'] = theme('comment_submitted', $comment);

**Output**

[image]

**My expected result is**

- To print the **Name in first** and **time in second**.
- **Should not truncate**.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function in your `template.php` located in your theme's directory.

```
function phptemplate_comment_submitted($comment){
  return t('Submitted on @datetime by !username.',
    array(
      '!username' => theme('username', $comment),
      '@datetime' => format_date($comment->timestamp)
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override any theme function implementing [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) in a module.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['comment_submitted'])) {
    $theme_registry['comment_submitted']['function'] = 'theme_mymodule_comment_submitted';
  }
}
```

In this case, as what you want is to override a string used by a module, [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) could help you. You just need to replace "Submitted by !username on @datetime." with "Submitted  on @datetime by !username."